# How to set initial value in directive property

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular2-directives

In this [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/NbNN8TtLndQiWekm3I3J?p=preview):
I have a attribute directive called `myTrimmer` that trims long text:

which works fine for static text

```
<div myTrimmer="10">some longgggg texttttttttttttttt</div>
```

but does not work for interpolated one:

```
<div myTrimmer="10">{{myText}}</div>
```

that means it takes empty string  instead of `myText`  at line

`this.originalValue = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;`

Here it is set property of directive:

```
  set myTrimmer(value: string) {
        this.originalValue = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
        this.length = +value;
        if (+value < this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML.length)
            this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML.substring(0, value) + '...';
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that this way you need to wait `AfterViewInit` event like this:

```
export class MyTrimmer {
  myTrimmer: string;
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.originalValue = this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    console.log(this.originalValue);
    this.length = +this.myTrimmer;
    if (+this.myTrimmer < this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML.length)
      this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML = 
this.el.nativeElement.innerHTML.substring(0, this.myTrimmer) + '...';
  }
}
```

See also at this updated plunkr https://plnkr.co/edit/MccvTyQxSpcgO6Tj99QX?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

Its because angular doesn't compiled `{{myText}}` yet. to let angular compile the `{{myText}}` you need to postpone the trimmer function. in order to do that you can use javascript `setTimeout` function like this:

```
set myTrimmer(value: string) {
  var myTrim = this;
  setTimeout(function(){  
    myTrim .originalValue = myTrim .el.nativeElement.innerHTML;
    myTrim .length = +value;
    if (+value < myTrim .el.nativeElement.innerHTML.length)
        myTrim .el.nativeElement.innerHTML = myTrim .el.nativeElement.innerHTML.substring(0, value) + '...';
  });
}
```

edited [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Omt8xMnPWEX0l3NDEnkJ?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

You could just use a "TrimPipe" like this:

```
{{myText | trim:10}}
```

The pipe code:

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({name: 'trim'})
export class TrimPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(text: any, trimValue: number) {
    if (!text) {
      return '';
    }
    return text.substring(0, trimValue) + '...';
  }
}
```